# kubectl logs of pods if it contains 2 containers

Tags: kubernetes, kubectl, kubernetes-pod

I have the pod and it has 2 containers.
if i give the command "`kubectl logs pod_name`"
it does not list logs, i need to give container name along with this command.

Is there a way to display both the container logs when we give command "`kubectl logs pod_name`"?

Comment: Try this `kubectl logs nginx --all-containers=true`

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubectl/kubectl-commands#logs

Comment: Thanks What is the kubernetes Rest API i need to use for this

Comment: https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/ ..............or https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/

Answer (score 16):

To display the logs of a particular container

```
kubectl logs <pod-name> -c <container_name>
```

To display all containers logs use below command

```
kubectl logs <pod-name> --all-containers=true
```

Comment: Thanks What is the kubernetes Rest API i need to use for this

Comment: Use the highest debug level `-v9`, probably you will get the API details, example `kubectl logs -f <pod-name> -v9`

Answer (score 1):

The rest API to get logs of a pod is

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/log
```

You can pass container as a query param to above API to get logs of a particular container

```
GET /api/v1/namespaces/{namespace}/pods/{name}/log?container=containername
```

When you hit above APIs from code using a service account or a user you need to have below [RBAC](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/access-authn-authz/rbac/) `Role` and `RoleBinding`

```
apiVersion: rbac.authorization.k8s.io/v1
kind: Role
metadata:
  namespace: default
  name: pod-logs-reader
rules:
- apiGroups: [""]
  resources: ["pods/log"]
  verbs: ["get", "list"]
```

The API is documented [here](https://kubernetes.io/docs/reference/generated/kubernetes-api/v1.19/#read-log-pod-v1-core)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to follow the logs in real time, add `-f` suffix.

```
kubectl logs -f <your-pod> --all-containers=true
```